# Positioning of tikzpicture in tabularx

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx

How can I remove the space above and left of the tikzpicture?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6,my style/.append style = {axis lines = middle, xlabel = {$x$}, x label style = {anchor = north west}, ylabel = {$y$}, y label style = {anchor = south east}, minor grid style = gray!20, scale mode = scale uniformly}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}
            \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}X|}{$f$ ist in $\mathopen[0,3\mathclose]$ \textbf{linksgekrümmt} (oder \textbf{konvex})} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}X}{$g$ ist in $\mathopen[0,3\mathclose]$ \textbf{rechtsgekrümmt} (oder \textbf{konkav}) } \\
            \hline
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
            \begin{axis}[
            scale=0.5,
            my style,
            grid=both,
            minor x tick num=1,
            xmin=-0.2, xmax=3.2,
            minor y tick num=1,
            ymin = -1.7, ymax = 1.7
            ]
            \addplot[draw=blue,domain=0:3,samples=100]{4/9*(x-1.5)^2-1/2}node[left,blue]{$f$};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            & 
            Die Tangentensteigungen von $f$ in $\mathopen[a,b\mathclose]$ werden grösser.
            &
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
            \begin{axis}[
            scale=0.5,
            my style,
            grid=both,
            minor x tick num=1,
            xmin=-0.2, xmax=3.2,
            minor y tick num=1,
            ymin = -1.7, ymax = 1.7
            ]
            \addplot[draw=blue,domain=0:3,samples=100]{-4/9*(x-1.5)^2+1/2}node[left,below,blue]{$g$};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &
            Die Tangentensteigungen von $g$ in $\mathopen[a,b\mathclose]$ werden kleiner.\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture in tabularx]

Comment: use `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]` for removing the space at the top of the tikzpicture

Comment: did the answer help you -- if so, consider accepting with a green tick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. x and y `tick label` reduced font size to `scriptsize`
2. remove space on left of first column with `@{}`
3. using `baseline = center`
4. using `makecell` package to split column 2 and 4
5. using `xshift` and `yshift` to shift labels closer to axes

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz,makecell}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6,my style/.append style = {axis lines = middle, xlabel = {$x$}, x label style = {anchor = north west}, ylabel = {$y$}, y label style = {anchor = south east}, minor grid style = gray!20, scale mode = scale uniformly}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize, yshift=0.7ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize, xshift=0.5ex}}



\begin{document}
\noindent
        \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc}
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize $f$ ist in $\mathopen[0,3\mathclose]$ \textbf{linksgekrümmt} (oder \textbf{konvex})} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize $g$ ist in $\mathopen[0,3\mathclose]$ \textbf{rechtsgekrümmt} (oder \textbf{konkav}) } \\
            \hline
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \begin{axis}[
            scale=0.5,
            my style,
            grid=both,
            minor x tick num=1,
            xmin=-0.2, xmax=3.2,
            minor y tick num=1,
            ymin = -1.7, ymax = 1.7
            ]
            \addplot[draw=blue,domain=0:3,samples=100]{4/9*(x-1.5)^2-1/2}node[left,blue]{$f$};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            & 
            \makecell[l]{\footnotesize Die Tangentensteigungen  \\\footnotesize von $f$  in $\mathopen[a,b\mathclose]$ \\\footnotesize werden grösser.}
            &
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \begin{axis}[
            scale=0.5,
            my style,
            grid=both,
            minor x tick num=1,
            xmin=-0.2, xmax=3.2,
            minor y tick num=1,
            ymin = -1.7, ymax = 1.7
            ]
            \addplot[draw=blue,domain=0:3,samples=100]{-4/9*(x-1.5)^2+1/2}node[left,below,blue]{$g$};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &
            \makecell[l]{\footnotesize Die Tangentensteigungen  \\\footnotesize von $g$  in $\mathopen[a,b\mathclose]$ \\\footnotesize  werden kleiner.}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```